# shell sleep inside the 'if' statement

Tags: python, bash, shell, sleep

I have a shell script that run a python script,
shell script contains a lot of "if" statements.
Simple example of **runner.sh** (`[1=1] is just for example`):

```
if [ 1=1 ];  then
    export DB_NAME="test_1"
    sleep 5;
    python ~/tmp/test_sleep/test.py $DB_NAME;
fi &

if [ 1=1 ];  then
    export DB_NAME="test_2"
    sleep 5;
    python ~/tmp/test_sleep/test.py $DB_NAME;
fi &

if [ 1=1 ]; then
    export DB_NAME="test_3"
    sleep 5;
    python ~/tmp/test_sleep/test.py $DB_NAME;
fi &

if [ 1=1 ]; then
    export DB_NAME="test_4"
    sleep 5;
    python ~/tmp/test_sleep/test.py $DB_NAME;
fi

# wait for background processes to finish
CHILD_ERROR=0
for CHILD_PID in `pgrep -P $$`
do
    # store child error if any
    wait $CHILD_PID || CHILD_ERROR=$?
done
```

And test.py:

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
import sys

print "%s at %s" % (sys.argv[1], strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", gmtime()))
```

Expected that each statement will sleep for 5 seconds before execution, but when I run it I see that runner.sh wait 5 second and then run all .py scripts in the same time:

```
test_2 at Sun, 04 Feb 2018 13:42:56 +0000
test_1 at Sun, 04 Feb 2018 13:42:56 +0000
test_3 at Sun, 04 Feb 2018 13:42:56 +0000
test_4 at Sun, 04 Feb 2018 13:42:56 +0000
```

So the question is how to make sleep work inside the "if" statement?
I can't make it outside cause I need to check a lot of if's (that's why I have `fi &` )

I know that all `ifs` running on background and sleep work for each process, all I need that those background processes start with some sleep delay (that have to increased for each statement).

For example 30s for 1st, +30s for next one and so on.

Comment: The `sleep` commands *are* working; they are all just started simultaneously, because each `if` statement is run in the background.

Comment: And because background processes are asynchronous, they aren't guaranteed to finish in the order they start.

Comment: TLDR, there is no question at all here. Run `bash`  with `-x` option to analyze the program flow.

Comment: @chepner, yeah, my question was not clear enough, sorry, I updated it. My problem is to create some delay that will not allow start all processes simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to sleep *between* starting the background jobs, not *in* each background job.

```
startJob1=1
startJob2=1
startJob3=1
startJob4=1


if [ "$startJob1" = 1 ]; then
  python ~/tmp/test_sleep/test.py "test1" & job1Pid=$!
  sleep 5
fi

if [ "$startJob2" = 1 ]; then
  python ~/tmp/test_sleep/test.py "test2" & job2Pid=$!
  sleep 5
fi

if [ "$startJob3" = 1 ]; then
  python ~/tmp/test_sleep/test.py "test3" & job3Pid=$!
  sleep 5
fi

if [ "$startJob4" = 1 ]; then
  python ~/tmp/test_sleep/test.py "test4" & job4Pid=$!
fi
```

Comment: thanks!
`sleep between starting the background jobs, not in each background job`
This is exactly where I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to queue all jobs at the start and have them started at different times, you must have differet sleep periods.

I used a function which is possible when each if-blok has similar commands.
I added `set -x` for debugging purpose only.
I use db_name in lowercase, better for showing it is not a system var.

```
sleep_time=0

test_starter() {
    export db_name="$1"
    ((sleep_time+=5))
    echo " Queuing ${db_name}, starts over ${sleep_time} seconds"
    (sleep ${sleep_time}; set -x; python ~/tmp/test_sleep/test.py ${db_name} )&
}

if [ 1=1 ];  then
    test_starter "test_1"
fi

if [ 1=1 ];  then
    test_starter "test_2"
fi

if [ 1=1 ]; then
    test_starter "test_3"
fi

if [ 1=1 ]; then
    test_starter "test_4"
fi

echo "Everything started"

# wait for background processes to finish
CHILD_ERROR=0
for CHILD_PID in `pgrep -P $$`
do
    # store child error if any
    wait $CHILD_PID || CHILD_ERROR=$?
done
```

Comment: if-else blocks have different statements with different count of input args. But thank you, this is one more great solution!

Comment: When you want to queue all different jobs in different if-blocks, you can change `test_starter()` into `get_sleeptime()` (returning 5 seconds more each call) and perform the `(sleep ..)&` in your if-block.